# Color scatterplot points based on rank

Tags: r, plot, colors, scatter-plot

I have a scatterplot of mtcars and I was wondering if there is way to specify the color of the points corresponding to the maximum and minimum mpg values. I guess a broader way to ask the question would be is there a way to assign point color based on subgroups, ie 3 most efficient cars in green and 3 least efficient cars in red?

```
plot(mpg~hp, col= "red", data= mtcars)
```

thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass in a vector of colors. As soon as you know which one is min/max, this is pretty straightforward. Also notice how `formula` works. You should not be specifying the `data.frame`.

```
with(mtcars, ifelse(mpg %in% c(min(mpg), max(mpg)), yes = "red", no = "black"))

# used directly in plot() because we specified data = mtcars
plot(mpg ~ hp, col = ifelse(mpg %in% c(min(mpg), max(mpg)), "red", "black"), data = mtcars)
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this with more than just one point? Could I maybe specify the 3 highest and 3 lowest

Comment: @JamesWilson there are a number of ways. One is using `quantile` function.